# How can I connect two different MongoDB clusters to my Express.js backend using a single server.js file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

in my MERN stack project, I want to connect two clusters from different MongoDB projects to my express js server in one code only "server.js". I've tried to do it in 2 sway but I can't reach my aim

the first way is using `mongoose.connect` 2 times.
the second way is using `mongoose.connect` and `mongoose.creatConnection`: in this case, i received an error saying that I can't use `mongoose.creatConnection().then()`

here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let refreshTokens = [];
app.use(express.json());

//first connection 
mongoose
  .connect(
// in my case i use my real <password> 
    "mongodb+srv://Nacer:<password>@cluster0.fnv49eh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connecté à MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((erreur) => {
    console.error("Erreur de connexion à MongoDB:", erreur);
  });

//second connection
mongoose
  .connect(
// in my case i use my real <password> 
    "mongodb+srv://nacereddine:<password>@cluster0.fnv49eh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connecté à MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((erreur) => {
    console.error("Erreur de connexion à MongoDB:", erreur);
  });
// data general forme
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  isAdmin: Boolean,
});
const users = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

I try to connect two MongoDB clusters to my database in the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `createConnection` method,

Save the below connection code in a file named `connect.js`, so you can reuse the code for the second connection,
This will return a db connection object,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
module.exports = (name, connString) => {
    const db = mongoose.createConnection(connString);
    db.on('connected', () => {
        console.info(`${name} MongoDB connection succeeded!`);
    });
    db.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`${name} MongoDB connection failed, ` + err);
        db.close();
    });
    db.on('disconnected', () => {
        console.info(`${name} MongoDB connection disconnected!`);
    });
    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
        mongoose.connection.close().then(() => {
            winston.info(`${name} Mongoose connection disconnected through app termination!`);
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
    // EXPORT DB OBJECT
    return db;
}
```

Create the first connection in your `server.js` file,

- replace the "first connection URL" with your cluster connection URL
- use the `firstConn` object to create a model

```
/** 
 *  FIRST DB CONNECTION
 *  ===================
 * */

// CONNECT DB
const firstConn = require("./connect")(
  "First", // just to print the connection name in the console
  "first connection URL"
);
// CREATE MODEL & SCHEMA
const FirstSchema = firstConn.model(...);
```

Create the second connection below the first connection, use the same way as the first,

- replace the "second connection URL" with your cluster connection URL
- use the `secondConn` object to create a model

```
/** 
 *  SECOND DB CONNECTION
 *  ===================
 * */

// CONNECT DB
const secondConn = require("./connect")(
  "Second", // just to print the connection name in the console
  "second connection URL"
);
// CREATE MODEL & SCHEMA
const SecondSchema = secondConn.model(...);
```

For a quick demo check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/turivishal/mongodb-multiple-server-connections).